# Problem with twocolumn ledger format in scrbook

Tags: margins, koma-script, two-column

currently I am trying to get a thesis in architecture into a ledger (tabloid, double letter) formatted srcbook document. The issue is that it should have twocolumns - at least for the main part of the investigation - and that LaTeX does somehow not like it. I always get the warning: *Package typearea warning: Bad type area settings! The detected line width is about 128% larger that...*

If I let it calculate the DIV value it is all very scrumbled up at the left hand side of the document, so it seems necessary to use a higher DIV value in order to have a nice distributed page (at least using the space a bit better).
In addition to that I get a very bad distribution on the pages following the first page of each chapter and have no clue how to organize it better. What package might help? 
Just for if it is important: I use pdflatex with MikTeX.

Here my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
paper=280mm:432mm,  % Papierformat: doble carta/ ledger
pagesize,           % stellt Ausgabeformat ein
DIV=14,             % Satzspiegel regeln
landscape,          % Querformat 
BCOR=10mm,          % Binderand. Wird dann noch abgezogen
12pt]               % Schriftgrösse
{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage{fontenc}        % Schrift (Font) 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % hier kann man die Sprache des Dokuments einstellen
\usepackage{scrpage2}       % um Seiten einzurichten 
\usepackage{multicol}       % mehrere Spalten
\pagestyle{scrheadings}     % Seitenlayout
\linespread{1.2}

\begin{document}
   \chapter{Test}
   \begin{multicols*}{2}
   \blindtext[10]
   \end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance! You work has already helped me a lot before.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the "DIV=calc" does not care about multicols. So you need to write something like DIV=20 and forget about the warning.

One mistake: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

OK, what else? KOMA-script improved the possibilities of two column layout: there is a new package called scrlayer-notecolumn. You can have an independent second column on the page (but without footnotes, I found out recently).